# Pressure tank to support half of house

Tags: pump

Presently i dont use any pump because 18psi water from water company is ok for basic and even shower. But i need more pressure for some rooms. My house GI pipes are rusty and I heard increasing the water pressure can make the rust come out of faucet even more. So I only plan to connect the main pump and pressure tank to half of the house only with new PPR plastic pipes put outside wall. So imagine before the main pump is a pipe divider where half of the water will go to house without passing through the pump. However my concern is when the main pump is sucking water, the pipes going direct to house without using pump would devoid of water temporarily. And people taking a bath in the direct pipes would suddenly have no water while pump is sucking to pressure tank. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I don't have the plumbing expertise to post an informed answer. But: seems like your concern is valid, and can be solved only by putting the pump at the whole house supply. You may find that increased pressure doesn't cause any trouble, other than perhaps new weeping at faucets that needed new gaskets anyway. If it does cause some sort of non-transient issue, such as the rust you are worried about, you can split the system _after_ the pump, and put a pressure-reducing valve on the side that you want to keep at a lower pressure.

Comment: This is great idea.. what kind of valve can reduce pressure from 40 psi back to 18 psi?

Comment: _"what kind of valve"_ -- I don't know for sure. All I know is that I used to own a home where the municipal water pressure was very high (around 70 psi, or maybe even more...I forget), and we had to install a pressure-reducing valve to reduce the stress on fixtures and appliances. We set it to 50 psi. I don't know if they are readily available to reduce to the current 18 psi you have, but [this one at Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Watts-3-4-in-Brass-FPT-x-FPT-Water-Pressure-Reducing-Valve-3-4-LF25AUB-Z3/202922385) will go down to 25 psi. That might be enough for your purposes.